# Resttemplate Returns 500 Response Message

Tags: resttemplate

I am trying to make a post request which is supposed to return a json, but for some reason it returns 500 something went wrong.

```
'''
public void templatRequestPayment(String token, String url, String key, String body)
    throws RestClientException, URISyntaxException, IOException {
    URI uri = new URI(url);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Authorization", token);
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
    headers.set("key", key);

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(body, headers);

    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate(getConverter());
    try {
        ResponseEntity<JsonNode> res = template.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, entity,
            JsonNode.class);
        String tok = res.getBody().toString();
        System.out.println(tok);
    } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
        ResponseEntity<String> st = 
 ResponseEntity.status(e.getStatusCode()).headers(e.getResponseHeaders())
            .body(e.getResponseBodyAsString());
        System.out.println(st.getHeaders() + "-- /n" + st.getBody());
    }

}

protected List<HttpMessageConverter< ?>> getConverter() {
    List<HttpMessageConverter< ?>> converters = Lists.newArrayList();
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    return converters;
}
```

'''